# What is BetterJsPop error on chrome?

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome

I am getting this error on Chrome with my React.js app. But on Mozilla it is working just fine. Does anybody know what it means or what is this error referring to?

```
VM1407:20 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot redefine property: BetterJsPop
at Function.defineProperty (<anonymous>)
at inject (<anonymous>:20:10)
at <anonymous>:510:11
at <anonymous>:511:11
```

Comment: Provide some code.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I figured out that it was "Fair Ad Block" chrome extension issue. I disabled and reenabled extensions and found the ad blocker was causing the issue. I removed the extension and my code is running very well again.

Comment: I was looking for a way to block BetterJsPop. Let me try this adblocker

Answer (score 2):

It's part of the "Better Js Popunder Script", a JavaScript library to show popup/popunder windows with advertisements (and break your navigation at the same time). I may well be included in some Chrome extensions.

http://code.ptcong.com/better-js-popunder-script/

Comment: I wonder if there's a way to detect this and show warning messages to my users that they have a dodgy browser extension installed...

Comment: @Dai, the JavaScript library in itself is nothing wrong with. It's used by some dodgy browser extensions, but detecting the library in use is by itself no problem.

Comment: How can I detect it, though?

Answer (score 1):

Its easy to solve in 2 STEPS:

1. disable adblocker extensions and cookies-tools extensions.
   (ex: fairAdblocker, ninja cookie)
2. Allow third party cookies in your browser config
   (For Chrome Users: settings->privacy and security->allow all cookies )
   Done, this should do the trick.

NOTE>>If you want to limit a little the privacy of the browser you can enable the permissions only to the affected url. Both the extensions (usually have a whitelist option) as well as the cookie settings (in the settings there is an option for Sites that can always use cookies).